# Google Maps Api Java script

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display a simple marker on my map. 
I follow all the steps as shown in the example but no markers attaches.

this is the block with script: 
which is the bug?

why don not I see the marker?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.1711696, 11.351473),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('object_map'),

        myOptions);  
        var marker= new google.maps.Marker ({ 
        position: LatLng, 
        title:"Mandolino"}); 

 }

   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize)


</script>
```

Comment: Care to share (that rhymes) your code ? v2 or v3 ? (p.s. i didnt downvote)

Comment: May u show me how to add markers?

Comment: You didnt create a marker ... what is `LatLng` ?

Comment: why not? this is the code found on google example...latlng means latitudelongitude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple example of creating markers on a map :

```
// this is list of markers with title / long and lat
var locations = [
      ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
      ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
      ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
      ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
      ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];

// This creates the map with zoom level / default center and map type
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 10,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

// this loops the array of marker locations
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { 
  // this creates the markers and adds them to the map 
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
     map: map
  });
}
```

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/QvNUF/95/

### Update

To add a single marker do this :

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: new google.maps.LatLng(<yourlat>, <yourlong>),
     map: <yourmap>
});
```

you will need to replace `<yourlat>` with the latitude of the marker position, `<yourlong>` with the longitude of your marker position and `<yourmap>` with the map variable you created

Comment: Var marker is not the marker?? this is what I found on google tutorial

Comment: I have updated my answer - you need to actually create a new google.maps.Marker object

Comment: This is what I found as example...so may you type the right code?

Comment: Create a http://jsfiddle.net/ with your code and then post a link to it here i will take a look

Comment: here is...I do not have result! However I see the map in the div id but do not see marker http://jsfiddle.net/mandolino/TNC4N/1/

Comment: There were lots of problems 1) div `id` quotes not closed 2) `MapTypeId` is case sensitive 3) CSS was wrong 4) `map: object_map` should be `map` 5) `initialize()` function not called .. working here -> http://jsfiddle.net/TNC4N/13/

Comment: oh..I am sorry this code doesn't show map on my Mac! I see  everything is ok and I see the marker I paste this code inside the script tag then I open the browser and I only see a frame blank!!

Comment: I would say thank you very much for your support and your patience..I am not able with Java and web application but I typed the code found on the google Api examples page..Thank you very much again!!!

Comment: About Css in general ...make it sense #left_col#object_data? I check on the CSS validator and the document seems to be ok! what do you think ? should I use only #object_data? thank you very much